# oracle sql developer not opening 19.2.1 after download window 10

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I download sqldeveloper-19.2.1.247.2212-x64.zip and unzip to C:\Program Files (x86)\sqldeveloper
Then click C:\Program Files (x86)\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper64.exe
And I get the error:

```
UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl$JDevStatusBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
java.lang.Error
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:731)
        at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:130)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:761)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1016)
        at oracle.bali.ewt.statusBar.StatusBar.updateUI(StatusBar.java:480)
        at oracle.bali.ewt.statusBar.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:104)
        at oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl$JDevStatusBar.<init>(StatusBarControl.java:264)
        at oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl.<init>(StatusBarControl.java:48)
        at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow$13.<init>(NbMainWindow.java:1098)
        at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow.createStatusBar(NbMainWindow.java:1098)
        at oracle.ide.IdeMainWindow.getStatusBar(IdeMainWindow.java:622)
        at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow.getStatusBarStatic(NbMainWindow.java:228)
        at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbStatusBar.getStatusLineElement(NbStatusBar.java:23)
        at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow$7.run(MainWindow.java:426)
        at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.getStatusLineElements(MainWindow.java:438)
        at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.decoratePanel(MainWindow.java:392)
        at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.access$100(MainWindow.java:81)
        at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow$2.run(MainWindow.java:269)
        at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl$Exclusive$1.run(WindowManagerImpl.java:1563)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Which version and edition of Windows do you have?

Comment: I was going to suggest you ask this question on [the dedicated Oracle SQL Dev forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/sql_developer) but I see @thatjeffsmith has popped up already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things...

1. i suggest NOT putting sql developer into program files
2. i suggest you run the sqldeveloper.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\sqldeveloper directory instead
3. if that doesn't work, delete the entire directory, and re-extract the files from the Zip you download using windows explorer (copy and paste)

Comment: thank you and I followed your instruction and it is fixed.